# How can "execute at begin node" be used with special characters like curly braces? (or: how to raise node content)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, hooks

I'd like to define the following style:

```
test/.style={
    execute at begin node={\raisebox\{-0.2cm\}\{},
    execute at end node={\}}
}
```

and use it like

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    test/.style={
        execute at begin node={\raisebox\{-0.2cm\}\{},
        execute at end node={\}}
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[test,circle,draw] {g};    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But it seems to be wrong, as I get errors like `"! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup"` or `"Missing number, treated as zero"`.

I guess the problem is due to the braces. How can I escape them properly?

**EDIT**: From the answers it became clear that `\raisebox` alone (like I tried in my broken solution) would've somehow worked in my case (because the dimension was so small that it didn't change the node size (at least I can't see it), which is what I wanted). So I consider all answers correct that only handled this specific/simple case. Answers using `\smash` and `\phantom` solved the problem I had actually in mind (but which I didn't clearly formulate as a question). Thanks again for all the great answers! :)

**WARNING**: As already said by percusse, if one only wants to align the text baselines, don't use this! Instead, as described in the "Putting a Diagram in Chains" tutorial of the manual, use `text height` and `text depth` on all nodes to be aligned, e.g. `text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex`.

Comment: If this is illustrative of what you are trying to achieve you could just use `\tikzset{test/.style={yshift=-0.2cm}}`. The problem here is not the escaping of the characters but the fact that what you are trying to execute at the begin and end is _not_ code, but rather a code fragment.

Comment: @PeterGrill Ok, I'll try. I though it might work as I often see how this is used for activating and deactivating math mode ($ and $).

Comment: @PeterGrill `yshift` moves the whole node, I just want to move the text inside the node.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I want to do something with the node’s content (which, to my recollection, cannot be accessed by a key), I collect it in a savebox via the `lrbox` environment.

In the following example, the text is saved in the savebox `\qrrTikzNodeContent` and then, still in the `execute at end node` key, used.

Firstly it is typeset in `\phantom` so that the node gets re-sized appropriately (as if the content would be typeset as usual). The following `\usebox` command is firstly `\llap`ed to occupy the same horizontal space like its phantom-ed version, and than `\smash`ed so that it doesn’t occupy any vertical space.

I added some hopefully useful keys, that should help how `\raisebox` may affect the node:

- `phantom` re-sizes the node as if the content would be typeset in the usual way;
- `smash` deactivates re-sizing of the node as forced by `\raisebox`.

This does not work with the keys `text width` and `align` as `\tikz@atbegin@node` is executed after the minipage is applied that is used to realize those keys.

For this special use-case I want to point out that there’s also the `text depth` key.
For `<content>` without a depth setting this to `<value>` is like a `\raisebox{<value>}{<depth>}`.

The following code procudes a matrix of nodes:

```
  normal        raise            raise + phantom
text depth  raise + smash    raise + phantom + smash
```

Additionally it shows the baseline of the node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newsavebox\qrrTikzNodeContent
\newif\ifphantom% remove for 'clean' version
\newif\ifsmash  % remove for 'clean' version
\tikzset{
  nodes={draw,circle},
  bl/.style={append after command={\pgfextra{\draw[very thin] (\tikzlastnode.base west) -- (\tikzlastnode.base east);}}},% debug, remove for 'clean' version
  phantom/.is if=phantom,% remove for 'clean' version
  smash/.is if=smash,    % remove for 'clean' version
  raise/.style={
    execute at begin node={\begingroup\begin{lrbox}{\qrrTikzNodeContent}},
    execute at end node={\end{lrbox}% remove for 'clean' version
      \ifphantom
          \phantom{\usebox\qrrTikzNodeContent}%
      \fi
      \ifsmash\smash{\fi
        \ifphantom\llap{\fi
          \raisebox{#1}{\usebox\qrrTikzNodeContent}%
        \ifphantom}\fi
      \ifsmash}\fi
      \endgroup
    },
%    execute at end node={\end{lrbox}% 'clean' version
%      \phantom{\usebox\qrrTikzNodeContent}%
%      \smash{%
%        \llap{%
%          \raisebox{#1}{\usebox\qrrTikzNodeContent}%
%        }%
%      }%
%      \endgroup
%    }
  },
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[draw=none, append after command={}, row sep=1ex, column sep=1ex] {
      \node[bl,                            ] {g}; &
      \node[bl, raise=-.2cm,               ] {g}; &  % only raisebox
      \node[bl, raise=-.2cm,        phantom] {g}; \\ % phantom
      \node[bl, text depth=-.2cm           ] {g}; &  % text depth
      \node[bl, raise=-.2cm, smash,        ] {g}; &  % smash
      \node[bl, raise=-.2cm, smash, phantom] {g}; \\ % smash + phantom
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[draw=none, append after command={}, row sep=1ex, column sep=1ex] {
      \node[bl,                            ] {h}; &
      \node[bl, raise=-.2cm,               ] {h}; &  % only raisebox
      \node[bl, raise=-.2cm,        phantom] {h}; \\ % phantom
      \node[bl, text depth=-.2cm           ] {h}; &  % text depth
      \node[bl, raise=-.2cm, smash,        ] {h}; &  % smash
      \node[bl, raise=-.2cm, smash, phantom] {h}; \\ % smash + phantom
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting! So many options one has now. So in my case I would need the `raise=-.2cm, smash, phantom` combination as I don't want the node size to be changed. I guess this particular combination is similar to mwibrow's solution.

Comment: @neo I have added the `phantom` and `smash` switch so that you can see that a simple `\raisebox` might not necessarily be everything you need to do. You can either remove the switches (`.as if` keys, `\if<switch>` and `\fi`) or create an extra style: `<name>/.style={raise=#1, smash, phantom}`

Comment: Ah! In my case, 0.2cm was so small that it didn't change the size of the node! That's why I thought that it would work for all dimensions. Now I really understand why your solution offers `phantom` and `smash`.

Comment: (or at least I didn't see that the size was changed)

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\newbox\collectbox
\tikzset{
    raise text/.style={
        execute at begin node={\setbox\collectbox=\hbox\bgroup},
        execute at end node={%
            \egroup%
            \phantom{\copy\collectbox}%
            \kern-\wd\collectbox%
            \smash{\raisebox{#1pt}{\box\collectbox}}}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \y in {-5,-4,...,5}
    \tikz\node [raise text=\y, circle, draw] {g}; 

\end{document}
```

Obviously the use of `\smash` means the text isn't taken in to account when calculating the bounding box (which isn't a problem in this case as the text is inside the node path).

[image]

**EDIT:** Actually, I see this is, in essence, identical to the answer given by *Qrrbrbirlbel* above, only mine is a bit less versatile.

Comment: If I see it correctly, your code handles Qrrbrbirlbel's `raise=-.2cm, smash, phantom` case, right?

Answer (score 7):

I would strongly recommend not doing this since what you have in mind is valid for `matrix` cells but not for regular nodes. In fact, for the regular node handling, it's not just *grab whatever is provided between`{}`* but more complicated text color,font etc. adjustments take place. You can instead do your adjustments by `text height,text depth` etc. tools provided or put a label style externally.

But if you want to get a little adventurous then you need to give a little care for your group not to be closed (in this context delimiters matched) too quickly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    test/.style={
        execute at begin node=\raisebox{#1}\protect\begingroup,
        execute at end node=\endgroup
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-5,0) rectangle (5,3);
                \foreach\x in{-10,-9,...,10}{
        \node[circle,draw,test=\x mm] at (4*\x mm,1.5){g};
                }
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

See how box raise amount is pushing the box in the reverse direction (which is another evidence for why you should not do this.

Comment: Why is `\raisebox` working in the opposite direction here?

Comment: @neo The box is first placed without knowing that the contents are going to be stretched so the box is placed in the base anchor as it is (`protect` is hiding the information) . It's kind of a hack but avoids extra register allocation. I have updated the example.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2]{standalone} 

\tikzset{test/.style={yshift=-0.15cm}}
\newcommand{\MyNode}[2]{
        \node (#1) at (#2) [test,circle,draw] {\phantom{#1}};    
        \node [test] at (#1) {#1};
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \MyNode{g}{0,0}
        \MyNode{h}{1,0}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the simplicity, but I don't like the `newcommand` -- having such thing as a style (as in mwibrow's answer) has more flexibility I guess.

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to raise the node content you can use

```
\tikzset{test/.style={yshift=-0.2cm}}
```

[image]

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is not with escaping the curly braces, but rather with code fragments.

Comment: Well, this also raises the node itself and not only the node content. What I want to do is change the text baseline (if it's called like that) in some situations, and most people seem to use `\raisebox` even in tikz for that.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first of all I don't think that a key `execute at begin node` actually exists in TikZ. There is however `execute at begin scope`, maybe you want to use that.

Now about the escaping of braces: You don't have to use braces around the code for `execute at...`. Instead just put your code on one line and use `\bgroup` and `\egroup`:

```
test./style={
    execute at begin scope=\bgroup\raisebox{-0.2cm}
    execute at end scope=\egroup
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve with this code, so my answer may not be exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: What a shame, it compiles but doesn't cause any effect. `execute at begin node` does indeed exist, have a look at the pgf manual. Although I can't use it with your proposed way of using `\bgroup` and `\egroup`.

Comment: The key `execute at begin node` exists but it is not documented...

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Thanks! :)

Comment: @alexraasch: Actually there are `execute at begin picture`, `execute at begin scope`, `execute at begin to`, `execute at begin node` and `execute at begin cell` (plus the respective `execute at end...`) and also `execute at empty cell`.