Tikz: How to vertically align text across multiple nodes?
The title says it. In the example below, how can I make the text start from the top in all boxes? So node3, node1, node2 to be on the same top line, like node3 is right now? I have checked this, this, this, this posts, none seem to answer my question. I tried playing with text depth, text height, minimum height,  minimum width, I haven't figured it out.

Code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        neutralnode/.style={rectangle, draw=black, fill=white, very thick, minimum width = 40mm,  minimum height = 65mm, align = center, anchor = base north, text depth = 2cm, text height = 2cm},
        ]

        %Nodes
        \node[neutralnode]      (node1)                             {node1 \\ Lorem ipsum.};
        \node[neutralnode]      (node2)      [right=of node1]       {node2 \\ Lorem ipsum \\ dolor sit amet.};
        \node[neutralnode]      (node3)      [left=of node1]        {node3 \\ Lorem ipsum \\ dolor sit amet, \\ consetetur sadipscing \\ elitr.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


The problem of valignment of a nodes text is well explained and solved here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140191/245790 , while a double-node solution is given there as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139723/245790 (which I'd use / had thought of)

Thanks. So I added that whole code chunk starting with \def\tikz@valign{c}  from your first link and used valign = top as argument for the \node[] command. But then, the align = center argument becomes redundant and the newline commands \\ inside the text boxes get ignored, hence everything is written on one line. To circumvent this I can write the text as a table, then every line is on a new row.

Ok. To present your table solution you can answer your question. Might be interesting for others, too. Thank you

The tcolorbox package does this natively. Here I'm using the fitting library, which gives tcolorboxes fixed dimensions. To space them, I've placed jumps \hspace{1cm}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[fitting]{tcolorbox}

\newtcboxfit{\mybox}{colback=white,colframe=black, width=4cm,height=6.5cm,halign=center,
sharp corners,nobeforeafter}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering

\mybox{node3 \\ Lorem ipsum \\ dolor sit amet, \\ consetetur sadipscing \\ elitr.}
\hspace{1cm}
\mybox{node1 \\ Lorem ipsum.}
\hspace{1cm}
\mybox{node2 \\ Lorem ipsum \\ dolor sit amet.}

\end{figure}

\end{document}


