# Modify font for all text in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I created a `newcommand` like this: `\newcommand{\txtDBC}[1]{\contour{white}{#1}}` and I want to apply it on all text and math formula in a tikzpicture.

The first was to declare a specific font using `font` keyword:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But my `\txtDBC` command need one parameter. How can I rewrite it for using it as the `\small` command? Maybe another solution can be used.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{esvect,tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\newcommand{\vecteur}[1]{\protect\vv{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtDBC}[1]{\contour{white}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=blue]{\txtDBC{$\vecteur{aa}$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**
[image: aa]

**Expected syntax:**

```
...
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\txtDBC]
\node[blue]{$\vecteur{aa}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @cfr I update my post

Comment: For [font=\small] \small will appear in several macros, sometimes in front of \tiks@text@action, sometimes in front of \else, so adding an argument won't work.  If I could find a macro that takes the text for a node as an argument (\pgftext is not it), I could replace it.

Comment: Maybe I can rewrite the command and create a command that takes no argument. But I don't know how I can do this....

Comment: @JohnKormylo do you mean `\pgfnodeparttextbox`? otherwise I am afraid there is no such macro because `\tikz\node{\verb|%|};` compiles.

Comment: A tip for your: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88517/how-can-execute-at-begin-node-be-used-with-special-characters-like-curly-brace

Comment: This is my try with `\pdfliteral` which is not drawing contours of a box and therefore catching a content of a node is useless: https://www.overleaf.com/read/zcbnnkbgnhsz. It might help.